# Create array from foreach loop with key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I couldn't quite find the exact solution that I am looking for.

I am trying to create an array from a foreach loop that retains the key.  Here is the code I have so far but it only keeps the last value in the array:

```
foreach($links as $link) {
  //runs scrape_amazon function for each of the links
  $ret = scrape_amazon($link);

  foreach($ret as $key => $value) {
    //echo $key; 
    //echo $value;
    $final_results[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

Could anyone help with a solution to keep all the values and the keys?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking for an array of keys?

Comment: Based on the way you're using the foreach loop it looks to me like your initial array would already have to be in the format of $ret[key] = value?

Comment: Your code should end up with `$final_results` being an exact copy of `$ret` (assuming it was empty to begin with). What did you expect to happen?

Comment: No I have a function that gathers data and puts it into $ret but each time it runs it overwrites the previous values.  I'm trying to keep the key and value such as:  [ASIN] => 123445 [Name] => Name [Retail] => 14.99.

Comment: Then the problem is not with the code you provided, but with when you assign values to `$ret`. The above simply creates an exact duplicate of `$ret` and places it in to `$final_results`, as Jon says.

Comment: I forgot to copy a section of the code.  What I want it to do is build an array each time it runs the scrape_amazon function.

Answer (score 8):

Based on your most recent comment, this should solve your problem:

```
$ret = array();

foreach($links as $link) {
  $ret[] = scrape_amazon($link);
}
```

Each time `scrape_amazon()` is called, it'll add the array returned to `$ret` making it into an array of arrays.

Comment: Yep.  That does it to and creates a multidemensional.  Thanks!

Comment: @Reg - Seeing that you're new on this site, I just thought I'd kindly remind you to accept the answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need an array of just keys, you need to do this

```
$ret_keys = array_keys($ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

why did you do that ? it's look like :

```
$final_results = $ret;
```

Comment: I know $final_results is returning the same as $ret. That's the problem. I was think of using array_push but couldn't get it to work to build the results of $ret each time into a single $final_results array.

Comment: the only solution you have is : $final_results[] = $ret; or $final_results[$ret['ASIN']] = $ret;

Comment: Thank you.  I see now the problem is it has to be multidemensional because there are 3 keys.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

```
  // Create an empty array first      
  $final_results = array();
  foreach($links as $link) {
      //runs scrape_amazon function for each of the links
      $ret = scrape_amazon($link);
      $final_results[] = $ret; // DONE :)
  }
```